# Execve cd /bin pwd [C]

Tags: c, bin, chdir, execve, getcwd

**I am currently writing a shell in C (school project). My cd and pwd is working. But when I do: cd /bin and after pwd, pwd shows /usr/bin. For me it looks like execve with pwd can't handle /bin but why?**

```
name% ./myshell
name: cd
Current working dir: /nfs/homes/name
name: cd /bin
Current working dir: /usr/bin
name: exit
```

Here I was working with getcwd(). But also when I pass pwd to Execve it is the same resulut.
I fixed the problem.

But I want to know why this happens and are there other folders that are not working?

```
int ft_cd(char *path)
{
    if (!path)
        chdir(getenv("HOME"));
    else if (chdir(path))
        ft_printf("bash: cd: %s: No such file or directory\n", path);
    if (!ft_strcmp(path, "/bin") || !ft_strcmp(path, "/bin/"))
        return (1);
    return (0);
}
```

Now I am looking for cd /bin or cd /bin/. In this case, I print /bin when pwd is called.
ft_strcmp is almost thesame as strcmp.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `ls -l /bin` and you will see it is a symlink to `/usr/bin`.

Since your `pwd` code (presumably using [`getcwd()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html)) doesn't know how you arrived in `/usr/bin`, it reports that name (the physical name for the directory) rather than `/bin` (the logical name).

Look at the POSIX specification for the  [`cd`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) command, and you'll see the `-L` (logical) and `-P` (physical) options. Your command is effectively implementing the `-P` option (only).  Also look at the POSIX specification for the [`pwd`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pwd.html_) command; similar comments apply.

Comment: thank you. I added the path after cd to my ENV pwd vaiable and now pwd works with -P and -L.